# How to limit the number of sites 3rd party javascript is deployed on?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, external-script

I've written a 3rd party JS application which I want to start selling to customers. I've been thinking of a pay-per-deployed-site charging scenario. The customer makes the purchase and gets a piece of HTML+JS to embed on their site that loads the actual JS application.

**Is there a reliable way in which I can make sure the customer only uses the application on the sites they payed for (they can easily just paste the above-mentioned code anywhere)?**

This is the only solution that came to my mind:

1. Check the address of the originating site using `window.location.href`
2. Send it with every request the JS application makes to my server
3. Compare it with a list of purchased sites registered by the customer upon the application purchase and block the application if the site is not recognized

However, such approach at first glance does not seem very reliable to me - e.g. I might have trouble if the customer's site is available under multiple addresses.

**Any ideas or even inspiration** on where to research further are very welcome (my current googling has been pretty futile so far).

Comment: No, there's no reliable technical way; this is a legal problem, not a technical one.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thx for your answer. Are you basically saying that the chosen charging model is incorrect because it's technically impossible? What would you recommend in my case?

Comment: It's a reasonable pricing model in my opinion, but it's very difficult to *enforce* technically unless you have some server-side component entirely within your control. Instead you control it with license agreements and contracts.

Comment: @jonrsharpe do you see technical challenges other than the one I mentioned in my question? This problem, well, is a problem ;) but I don't consider it a total showstopper just yet. It should work in the majority of cases. If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it if there's no better answer within the next few days :)